# ArrayindexoutofBounds in Android while splitting a string

Tags: android, arrays

I know this has been asked a lot,but i'm really sorry,i am a noob in this,i'll just attach the code,here

```
 l =adminUserlst.split(",");
      UsrList = new ArrayList<String>();
      for(i=0;i<=l.length-1;i++){
      DatabaseReference db33 =firebaseDatabase.getReference("USERS/");
          db33.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
              @Override
              public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                  ***String spl=dataSnapshot.child(l[i]).child("sList").getValue().toString();//.split(",");
                  splits =spl.split(",");
                  for(ii=0;ii<=splits.length-1;ii++){
                      UsrList.clear();
                      UsrList.add(splits[ii]);
                      usrAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, UsrList);
                      spinner.setAdapter(usrAdapter);

                  }

              }

              @Override
              public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

              }
          });


      }
```

I have some references in l,by which i want to extract some data from firebase database,so once i split the data,i'm using the split data present as a child node to get some more information,but for some reason i'm getting a
ArrayIndexOutofBounds:length=1;index=1 at ***

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Just check for 'less than' instead of 'less than or equal to' in a for-loop

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE should i do it in just one for loop or the second one as well ??

Comment: You typically do that in each for loop, because containers are zero-based (i.e. they have an index 0) while the length function returns the size which is not zero-based.

Answer (score 1):

check with writing your for loop condition in bracket
like this

`for(i=0;i<=(l.length-1);i++)`

on both places